# ERROR 1136: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql

I get the Error:

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.
```

But I've checked and rechecked my query and everything seems ok:

```
UPDATE
    table
SET
    col = 'enum(''FOO'',''BAR'')'
WHERE
    col1 = ''
AND
    col2 = 'val2'
AND
    col3 = 3;
```

I thought the table could have some triggers that were generating the error –I didn't design the system– but I can't find any.

I've found the same error with at least three different tables.

Note. The "enum" on line three is really supposed to be a string, not an enum type.

Comment: Are you sure this is the query that produces this error?

Comment: What does "show triggers from <dbname>" return?

Comment: @ypercube Yes I'm sure, I'm running it directly on my MySQL client.

Comment: @srivani Empty resultset, no triggers defined :-S

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently there were some triggers that updated another database, I don't know why `show triggers from <dbname>` returned an empty row set.

Apparently, when migrating their system, they had to ask support to create the triggers for them.

Answer (score 32):

It could be a few things, but here are two ideas:

-There is a trigger that needs to be changed/removed.

-The value that you are updating the cell to exceeds the column length. [Article on this.](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/mysql/column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just checked: 
There are no triggers in the database and the column I'm trying to update is defined as `text(65535)` so it's definitely not exceeding the length.

Comment: Are any of your table names or column names reserved words? Try surrounding your table name and column names with ``. (Grave accents)

Comment: Is anything in your updated value escaping / cancelling out the apostrophes? -- Same goes for val2.

Comment: Or does the column have PK/FK restrictions?

Comment: There are apostrphes, but properly escaped, I just tried the same query without them, and get the same error.

Comment: Nope, well, the PK is defined as col1, col2, col3 but I wouldn't think that was the problem.

Comment: Are you "escaping" the apostrophes with a another apostrophe? Instead you should use a backslash before the apostrophe. (i.e. replace '' with \')

Comment: Tried it, didn't help, also tried removing the apostrophes at all.

Comment: Is your update code small enough such that you could just post the actual update string here with as little editing as possible? If not, I'm fresh out of ideas.

Comment: OK, Here it is:  
    UPDATE
        data_dictionary
    SET
        column_type = 'enum(''FRT_A_EXAM'',''FRT_B_EXAM'', ''WONDERLIC'')'
    WHERE
        view_name = ''
    AND
        table_name = 'v_answer_sheets'
    AND
        ordinal_position = 3;

Comment: If your PK is defined as view_name, table_name, ordinal_position, how can view_name be null? -- Other than that, I don't know. Sorry. I created a table:  delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `data_dictionary` (
  `column_type` text NOT NULL,
  `view_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ordinal_position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`view_name`,`table_name`,`ordinal_position`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

Inserted a row, then updated it with your string and it worked. ... However, I used 'empty' for view_name rather than '' since it is a PK and not null.

Comment: As a matter of fact, checking the data, every row has an empty string on view_name, I tried the update leaving out the view_name field and it still failed.

Maybe the webhost upgraded mysql (version() reports 5.0.92) and now it doesn't accept empty strings on non null values.

Thanks for all your help. I welcome anything else you might think of.

Comment: Since view_name is part of the PK it might not allow you to do an update without it. Default settings don't like it. And you may have a point that you aren't allowed to search with empty strings. -- Another thing you could try, since view_name isn't being used, is to drop it from the PK and then drop the column. Insert another column with the same name and a default value of 'null' (a string spelling null). Then add it back to the PK. Now when you do your updates, try WHERE view_name = 'null'.

Comment: OK, this is weird. After doing what you suggested, I kept getting the same error, I then decided to drop completely the view_name column and run my update query –obviously without "WHERE view_name..."– that gave me another error "Unknown column view_name in WHERE clause".

Comment: I can't find any table that references this one :S

Comment: Create a new table, copy the data over, then try the update.  If it doesn't work, then we can narrow it down to being a problem with your / your host's settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Some time triggers create this issue as well. For example I have create a trigger to log the entries, when I add some field in master table and try to update the master table it display the same error. After some work around, I got the point and create the same field in log table and it fix the issue.