# MySQL wrong syntax only on other machines

Tags: c#, mysql, debugging

I have created a program that monitors the progress of projects for my company but as i am testing i am encountering a very bizzare problem. When i test it under **windows 10** in the pc it was created everything **runs** as expected. However when i test it in the computers of my co-workers that run **windows 7** and **8** i get the following **error** in the sql query code *"You have an error in your SQL syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'01 where teammember.Name="SomeName" and projects="SomeProject"' at line 1"* . The code that results to the error is below.

```
 public void UpdateHoursWorked(string teamMember, string projectName, float hoursWorked)
        {
            SetSafeUpdates(false);

            // Error HERE
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update memberprojects " +
                "join teammembers on Member = teammembers.TeamMembersID " +
                "join projects on Project = projects.ProjectsID " +
                "set HoursWorkedOnProject = HoursWorkedOnProject + " + hoursWorked + " " +
                "where teammembers.Name = \"" + teamMember + "\" and projects.ProjectName = \"" + projectName + "\"", conn))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Update the total hours worked in the projects table, and re-read the projects
            UpdateTotalHoursWorked(projectName, hoursWorked);

            OnUpdate(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
```

I can't seem to pin point the problem as under windows 10 the program works perfectly and the syntax looks correct to me. Any idea about what might cause the problem?

Comment: Well you could on error dump out the command so you can see what sql is being generated - parameters are a mighty fine choice and shouldnt be ignored..

Comment: Im not an MySQL type of guy, but i suspect the double quotes migth case issues ( result should look like `where teammember.Name='SomeName' and projects='SomeProject'`)

Comment: You should use parameters for your query.

Comment: I usually in these case copy the string from c# and do query directly in SQL Server Management Studio which has better error messages.  I suspect like BugFinder said that it would be fixed using parameters.  When you don't use parameters the driver has to guess the type of data and often guesses wrong.  Just like in excel where excel guesses and changes number to dates and dates to numbers.

Comment: Thanks guys, i'll will check your suggestions tomorrow morning, hopefully i'll solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your query using `Command.Parameters`. Also use `@` to concatenate strings on multiple lines. **Format** your query !

**Benefits:**

1) Problems like this will not occur

2) You are protected from sql injection

3) The code is read/written easier

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"
                 UPDATE
                     MemberProjects  
                 JOIN 
                     TeamMembers ON Member = TeamMembers.TeamMembersID
                 JOIN 
                     Projects ON Project = Projects.ProjectsID 
                 SET 
                     HoursWorkedOnProject = HoursWorkedOnProject +  @HoursWorked
                 WHERE
                     TeamMembers.Name = @Name AND
                     Projects.ProjectName = @ProjectName";

    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HoursWorked", hoursWorked);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", teamMember);    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", projectName);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I think you can see easily the difference between good formatting and using parameters. I advise you to write the Table names infront of Member, Project it will be easier to understand the location of this fields.

Comment: I changed the code to what you suggested and this has solved the problem i initially had but now i get _"Column count doesn't much value count at row 1"_ which is weird because yet again in **my computer** it run perfectly fine.

Comment: @Raftos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557307/error-1136-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1 from this answer the suggestions are there is some trigger(I suppose it is not this), or the value which you try to Set  HoursWorkedOnProject   exceeds the column length

Comment: I also tested the queries about to be executed in both machines and they are identical. What bugs me the most is that i have similar code that works just fine on all machines.

Comment: @Raftos check how it is defined HoursWorkedOnProject on other databases. It is possible to exceed the limit of the field.

Comment: Yeah, definitely something is wrong with HoursWorkedOnProject because i set it to 0 and the query worked fine. I look into it more.

Answer (score 0):

Try avoid double quotes sequence (and escape) using a proper alternance with single quotes

```
  "update memberprojects " +
  "join teammembers on Member = teammembers.TeamMembersID " +
  "join projects on Project = projects.ProjectsID " +
  "set HoursWorkedOnProject = HoursWorkedOnProject + " + hoursWorked + " " +
  "where teammembers.Name = '" + teamMember + "'  and projects.ProjectName = '" + projectName + "'", conn))
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the final issue. My computer was using English Windows but my co-workers all use Widndows in our native language. In my country decimal numbers are written using a comma (example 0,0) but in the us decimal numbers are written with a dot (example 0.0) so when other pcs sent data to the database it was wrong. To fix the issue i changed the **Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture** to **new CultureInfo("en-us")**