# MySQL UPDATE statement is throwing "Column count doesn't match value count" error

Tags: mysql

(**NOTE:** I know this is an error that's commonly asked about, but most of the time, the issue is in an `INSERT` statement. I couldn't find a question on this website where this error happened during an `UPDATE`.)

I have a table in MySQL (InnoDB / v. 5.7.19) called `RESULTS` which has, among others, two columns called `TYPE` and `STATUS`. Both are of type `ENUM`, with `PASS`, `FAIL` and `IGNORE` being the supported values in both. I'm trying to run this `UPDATE` statement on that table, using Workbench (also tried the same directly on the DB machine, using the mysql command):

```
update `RESULTS` set `TYPE`='IGNORE' where `STATUS`='IGNORE';
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Changing the single quotes to double quotes didn't help. I'm able to run this query successfully:

```
select count(`TYPE`) from `RESULTS` where `STATUS`='IGNORE';
```

I'm probably making a silly mistake here, but can anyone point out what's wrong with the `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: Look for any triggers registered as before/after update

Comment: The query is correct, the issue must be in the composition of your table/database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 1136: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557307/error-1136-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid , you're right, there was a trigger on that table. After I added the same column in the other table, it started working. I don't know why MySQL can't actually specify that the error is in the trigger, it would have saved me a lot of time. If you reply with this as the answer, I'll mark it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As requested I am posting it as an answer.

The error basically is self-explanatory like performing an operation on set of attributes but the values provided in the query are not enough. But in your case, you are performing an update operation with all attributes and their values and still, this error appears it may be a case that there is some trigger is registered for this table probably on before/after the event, If that is the case you need to update or remove that trigger if no needed.